# Importing external jar file in Android Studio---NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: jar, noclassdeffounderror, android-studio, build.gradle

I created a new project using Android Studio and copied a jar file into my application's libs. Then added it as a library, which made the IDE recognize it. Later, I added it to the `build.gradle` and it now compiles just fine. However, when I attempt to run the application on a device it crashes with `NoClassDefFoundError`.

Attached and in order:

1. The project tree on Android Studio. Notice the `test-jar-to-import.jar` inside `HelloSheepProject/HelloSheep/libs/`.
2. The contents of the `MainActivity.java`. It is attempting to create a new `MyFile`. Nothing else.
3. The `build.gradle` inside `HelloSheepProject/HelloSheep/`. I added the line `compile files('libs/test-jar-to-import.jar')`.
4. The contents of `MyFile.java`. It was created in Eclipse and exported as a jar file.
5. The error when I trying to run it on a device.

Any ideas on what I am missing? I have tried a `./gradlew clean` in `HelloSheepProject` but it didn't help.

---

[image]

---

```
package top.furrylamb.example.hellosheep;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;

import top.furrylamb.example.MyFile;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        MyFile myFile = new MyFile("hi", "there");
    }

}
```

---

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.5.+'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'android'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:13.0.+'
    //compile fileTree(dir: "libs", include: "*.jar")
    compile files('libs/test-jar-to-import.jar')
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 17
    buildToolsVersion "17.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 16
    }
}
```

---

```
package top.furrylamb.example;

public class MyFile {
    public final String left;
    public final String right;
    public MyFile(String left, String right) {
        this.left = left;
        this.right = right;
    }
}
```

---

```
07-19 19:26:33.855  13656-13656/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
        java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: top.furrylamb.example.MyFile
        at top.furrylamb.example.hellosheep.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:15)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5206)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1083)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2064)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2125)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:140)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1227)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4898)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1006)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:773)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

---

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I found the solution to my problem. Since I've been lost on this for hours I'll keep the thread instead of deleting it.

The jar I was importing had been compiled/exported with Java 7 in mind. Once I enabled compliance with Java 6 it worked fine.

To sum it up, when adding an external jar file in Android Studio:

1. Copy jar to root/project/libs folder;
2. Right-click and add as library;
3. Add the jar to root/project/build.gradle (something like `compile files('libs/test-jar-to-import.jar')`);
4. Make sure the imported jar complies with Java 6 (7 will not do, for now).

Comment: Your post just completed 3 hours of frustration, in my case drag and drop `~/sdk/extras/google/gcm/gcm-client/dist/gcm.jar` to newly created /libs off project and follow rest of your instructions. Thanks.

Comment: Thank you! I''d been at this for hours. My Android app uses Java 1.8 and my class library was set to JDK 8. Everything compiled but kept getting `com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_25\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1` when trying to run the app. Changed the class library's binary format to JDK 7 (from Netbeans project properties) and now it works! Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I was getting the same `NoClassDefFoundError` error at runtime, even though it compiled ok.  It had been working fine previously.  But one day, I added a new package to my app, which resulted in the package name-space being changed.  My jar had already been a part of the application's structure, so I was somewhat surprised at this new runtime error suddenly complaining about an unknown class in a jar library that was working previously.
The fix, in my case, was a simple Build->Clean Project.